# Erratic pull-up on ESP8266 UART

Tags: uart, esp8266, pullup

I have a logic-level UART connection between an STM8 and an ESP8266. The STM8 Tx goes to the ESP Rx through a 1 kΩ resistor, so that I can override the STM8 signal when I want to program the ESP8266. Normally, no programming device is connected.

On the STM8 side of the resistor, the signal is 3.3 V at idle and 0 V when active. On the ESP side of the resistor, it is usually the same, but sometimes the active state only goes down to 2.5 V.

This generally starts at the start of the first bit of a message, and may correct itself within the first bit, as in the scope trace below (note: x10 scope probes), or it may continue for the entire message.

As I understand it, the ESP8266 has a 27 kΩ pull-up, but I can't see a simple pull-up resistor producing this effect. What could be causing it?

[image: ESP8266 RXD0]